# Packets marked by iptables only sent to the correct routing table sometimes

Tags: iptables, openvpn, iproute2

I am trying to route packets generated by a specific user out over a VPN. I have this configuration:

```
$ sudo iptables -S -t nat
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE 

$ sudo iptables -S -t mangle
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner guy -j MARK --set-xmark 0xb/0xffffffff 

$ sudo ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local 
32765:  from all fwmark 0xb lookup 11 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 

$ sudo ip route show table 11
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6 
10.8.0.6 dev tun0  scope link 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0

$ sudo iptables -S -t raw
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner guy -j TRACE 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j TRACE
```

It seems that some sites work fine and use the VPN, but others don't and fall back to the normal interface. This is bad. This is a packet trace that used VPN:

```
Oct 27 00:24:28 agent kernel: [612979.976052] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:rule:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=23.1.17.194 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14494 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57502 DPT=80 SEQ=2294732931 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6E01D0000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999
Oct 27 00:24:28 agent kernel: [612979.976105] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:3 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=23.1.17.194 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14494 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57502 DPT=80 SEQ=2294732931 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6E01D0000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999
Oct 27 00:24:28 agent kernel: [612979.976164] TRACE: mangle:OUTPUT:rule:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=23.1.17.194 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14494 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57502 DPT=80 SEQ=2294732931 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6E01D0000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999
Oct 27 00:24:28 agent kernel: [612979.976210] TRACE: mangle:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=23.1.17.194 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14494 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57502 DPT=80 SEQ=2294732931 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6E01D0000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
Oct 27 00:24:28 agent kernel: [612979.976269] TRACE: nat:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=23.1.17.194 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14494 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57502 DPT=80 SEQ=2294732931 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6E01D0000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
Oct 27 00:24:28 agent kernel: [612979.976320] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=23.1.17.194 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14494 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57502 DPT=80 SEQ=2294732931 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6E01D0000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
Oct 27 00:24:28 agent kernel: [612979.976367] TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=23.1.17.194 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14494 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57502 DPT=80 SEQ=2294732931 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6E01D0000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
Oct 27 00:24:28 agent kernel: [612979.976414] TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:rule:1 IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=23.1.17.194 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=14494 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57502 DPT=80 SEQ=2294732931 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6E01D0000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
```

and this is one that didn't:

```
Oct 27 00:22:41 agent kernel: [612873.662559] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:rule:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=209.68.27.16 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45305 DPT=80 SEQ=604973951 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6B6960000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999
Oct 27 00:22:41 agent kernel: [612873.662609] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:3 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=209.68.27.16 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45305 DPT=80 SEQ=604973951 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6B6960000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999
Oct 27 00:22:41 agent kernel: [612873.662664] TRACE: mangle:OUTPUT:rule:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=209.68.27.16 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45305 DPT=80 SEQ=604973951 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6B6960000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999
Oct 27 00:22:41 agent kernel: [612873.662709] TRACE: mangle:OUTPUT:policy:2 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=209.68.27.16 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45305 DPT=80 SEQ=604973951 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6B6960000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
Oct 27 00:22:41 agent kernel: [612873.662761] TRACE: nat:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=209.68.27.16 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45305 DPT=80 SEQ=604973951 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6B6960000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
Oct 27 00:22:41 agent kernel: [612873.662808] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=209.68.27.16 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45305 DPT=80 SEQ=604973951 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6B6960000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
Oct 27 00:22:41 agent kernel: [612873.662855] TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA DST=209.68.27.16 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40425 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45305 DPT=80 SEQ=604973951 ACK=0 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A03A6B6960000000001030307) UID=999 GID=999 MARK=0xb
```

I have already tried "ip route flush cache", to no avail. I do not know why the first packet goes through the correct routing table, and the second doesn't. Both are marked.

Once again, I do not want ALL packets system-wide to go through the VPN, I only want packets from a specific user (UID=999) to go through the VPN. I am testing ipchicken.com and walmart.com via `links`, from the same user, same shell. walmart.com appears to use the VPN; ipchicken.com does not.

Any help appreciated. Will send 0.5 bitcoins to answerer who makes this fixed.

EDIT 2:

I have tried `iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -j NOTRACK` to circumvent conntrack interference, but this hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain that it is an issue with your ip route table. `0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0` only routes IP addresses that are below 128.0.0.0. If you add the following route 
`ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 table 11`, it should fix the issue.